# two separate classes doesn't share the same data c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have two different classes `PipeNetwork.hpp` `PipeNetwork.cpp` and `Tube.hpp` `Tube.cpp`

which `class Tube : public PipeNetwork`

the following function in PipeNetwork

```
void PipeNetwork::testing()
    {
        Tube u;
        u.length();
        std::cout << "function works fine" << std::endl;
    }
```

`length()` is functions located in `Tube`

```
void Tube::length()
    {
        std::vector<double>::iterator i;
        L.reserve(get_tubes_numbers());        // get_tubes numbers is function in PipeNetwork

            //bla bla bla
    }
```

```
int PipeNetwork::get_tubes_numbers()
    { 
        return tubes_numbers;
    }
```

and finally at `main`

```
int main()
{
   PipeNetwork Oral;
   Oral.InputData("Input.txt");
   Oral.testing();
   return 0;
}
```

what should happen:

1- `InputData` take some data and storing it in `PipeNetwork` class including `get_tubes_numbers()` which done fine

2- `testing` should get `get_tubes_numbers()` from PipeNetwork and preform calculation in `Tube` class

but the problem is `get_tubes_numbers()` alwayes return empty with 0 value

and according to my understanding, it's because `object u` is created separately from `object Oral` as shown in the image [what objects look like in visual studio 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EMVR.png)  [02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGkcj.png)

but `Tube u;` should be a subclass and subclass should share the same variables from the base class Or my understanding of the subclass is wrong? correct me, please.

how to solve this problem?

And thank you for your time

Comment: I'm confused. You create a new object with `Tube u;` and you are surprised it has nothing to do with your `PipeNetwork` object? Can you explain in English how this new `Tube` object is supposed to interact with your `PipeNetwork`, or what the overall goal of your `testing` method is?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: That's why I'm posting my question, I thought `Tube u;` will be a subclass which means sharing the same variable from the base class `PipeNetwork`. Correct me please if I'm wrong since I'm new to oop concept.

Comment: And I created `testing` to check `length` results before proceeding

Comment: *I'm new to oop concept* -- The issue has nothing to do with oop.  You created a local variable `u`, and when that function returns, that local variable is no more.  No different than if `u` were an `int`, `double`, or any other type.

Comment: I made that because I found a similar question on the website solved by creating an object to access the data. So, if I didn't create that object, how to access the data then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the testing class. You create a new object ***u*** that is initialized with default constructor. This cause your program to have all member of the class standard initialization. So `get_tubes_numbers()` return 0 because ***tubes_numbers*** variable is initialized to 0.

To solve this you can declare a constructor with parameters. In this case the best choice is to pass as parameter the base class `PipeNetwork` and initialize in the constructor the field you need.

This is an example of constructor you can implement:

```
Tube::Tube(PipeNetwork& base)
    {
        this->tubes_numbers = base.tubes_numbers;
    }
```

then you can just modify the code like this:

```
void PipeNetwork::testing()
    {
        Tube u(*this);
        u.length();
        std::cout << "function works fine" << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Would you please share similar example?

Comment: i add an example